# How do I check whether a user has 'checked' the checkbox & enable the submit button if checked else disable?

Tags: html, angular

I have seen the other answers as well, I ain't looking forward to show or hide a submit button, rather want it to be enabled or disabled if the checkbox is checked or not, respectively. I am working with Angularjs 2 & so looking for an answer in the same...
Here's the html code:

```
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2">
      <span>I have carefully read the agreement <br/>& agree to all Terms & Conditions</span>
      </center>
      <button md-raised-button class="md-raised" type="submit" id="but5" [disabled]="![checked]" style="margin-left:34px;">NEXT</button>
```

Comment: Please post some code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish. "I have seen the other answers as well, " is not very helpful if you don't link to them and point out why it doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I've added the html code, hope it is more clear now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@GünterZöchbauer's answer is almost correct. This is a solution you could use.

```
<input type="checkbox" #checkbox (change)="angular = checkbox.checked">
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!checkbox.checked ? true : null">
```

You could also use something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="object.selected" />
```

Comment: `(change)="true"` would probably do as well. I forgot that Angular doesn't do anything if there is no event subscribed to.

Comment: Thanks a lot @GünterZöchbauer & Cybey, it's working :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
<input type="checkbox" #checkbox>
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!checkbox.checked ? true : null">
```

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/jTsqFFLXTktPBheDqfuq?p=preview   pasted your code here, correct me if I've done something wrong